# PHP XML Parsing Erases Attribute Value

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I have the following code below:

```
<?php

$xml = '<Divisions xmlns="urn:description7a.services.chrome.com">
         <responseStatus responseCode="Successful" description="Successful"/>
         <division id="1">Acura</division>
         <division id="44">Aston Martin</division>
         <division id="4">Audi</division>
         <division id="45">Bentley</division>
         <division id="5">BMW</division>
         <division id="6">Buick</division>
         <division id="7">Cadillac</division>
         <division id="8">Chevrolet</division>
         <division id="9">Chrysler</division>
         <division id="11">Dodge</division>
         <division id="46">Ferrari</division>
         <division id="59">FIAT</division>
         <division id="13">Ford</division>
         <division id="170">Freightliner</division>
         <division id="15">GMC</division>
         <division id="16">Honda</division>
         <division id="17">Hyundai</division>
         <division id="18">Infiniti</division>
         <division id="19">Isuzu</division>
         <division id="20">Jaguar</division>
         <division id="21">Jeep</division>
         <division id="22">Kia</division>
         <division id="47">Lamborghini</division>
         <division id="23">Land Rover</division>
         <division id="24">Lexus</division>
         <division id="25">Lincoln</division>
         <division id="48">Lotus</division>
         <division id="53">Maserati</division>
         <division id="26">Mazda</division>
         <division id="61">McLaren</division>
         <division id="27">Mercedes-Benz</division>
         <division id="2">MINI</division>
         <division id="29">Mitsubishi</division>
         <division id="30">Nissan</division>
         <division id="34">Porsche</division>
         <division id="57">Ram</division>
         <division id="49">Rolls-Royce</division>
         <division id="52">Scion</division>
         <division id="42">Smart</division>
         <division id="37">Subaru</division>
         <division id="56">Tesla</division>
         <division id="39">Toyota</division>
         <division id="40">Volkswagen</division>
         <division id="41">Volvo</division>
      </Divisions>
';

$parse = simplexml_load_string($xml);

print_r($parse);
```

The problem is is that it's not keeping the attribute values in the xml like

```
<division id="1">Acura</division>
<division id="44">Aston Martin</division>
```

The PHP is erasing it to be like:

```
array (
  0 => 'Acura',
  1 => 'Aston Martin'
);
```

I'm passing this to JSON so I need it to stay in the format of an array, but need the indexes to be the value of the division ID attribute. This is what it's exactly outputting right now:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
    [responseStatus] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
        [@attributes] => Array ( 
            [responseCode] => Successful 
            [description] => Successful 
        ) 
    ) 
    [division] => Array ( 
        [0] => Acura 
        [1] => Aston Martin 
        [2] => Audi 
        [3] => Bentley 
        [4] => BMW 
        [5] => Buick 
        [6] => Cadillac 
        [7] => Chevrolet 
        [8] => Chrysler 
        [9] => Dodge 
        [10] => Ferrari 
        [11] => FIAT 
        [12] => Ford 
        [13] => Freightliner 
        [14] => GMC 
        [15] => Honda 
        [16] => Hyundai 
        [17] => Infiniti 
        [18] => Isuzu 
        [19] => Jaguar 
        [20] => Jeep 
        [21] => Kia 
        [22] => Lamborghini 
        [23] => Land Rover 
        [24] => Lexus 
        [25] => Lincoln 
        [26] => Lotus 
        [27] => Maserati 
        [28] => Mazda 
        [29] => McLaren 
        [30] => Mercedes-Benz 
        [31] => MINI 
        [32] => Mitsubishi 
        [33] => Nissan 
        [34] => Porsche 
        [35] => Ram 
        [36] => Rolls-Royce 
        [37] => Scion 
        [38] => Smart 
        [39] => Subaru 
        [40] => Tesla 
        [41] => Toyota 
        [42] => Volkswagen 
        [43] => Volvo 
    ) 
)
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXML is taking your group of `<division>` elements and creating an array out of them and assigning indexes as it sees fit.

What you can do is nest an `<id></id>` and `<name></name>` tag within each `<division></division>` element and then `foreach` your way through the new array of `SimpleXMLObjects` and get your data that way.

So if you have XML code that looks like this:

```
<divisions>
    <division>
        <id>16</id>
        <name>Honda</name>
    </divsion>
    <division>
        <id>45</id>
        <name>Bently</name>
    </division>
    <division>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Acura</name>
    </division>
</divisions>
```

You could process it like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("divisions.xml");
$divisions = array();

foreach($xml as $division)
{
    $divisions[(int)$division->id] = (string)$division->name;
}

var_dump($divisions);

//Var dump will produce an array of...

array (size=3)
  16 => string 'Honda' (length=5)
  45 => string 'Bently' (length=6)
  1 => string 'Acura' (length=5)
```

That will put all of your indexes in the right place.

Comment: The problem is is the simplexml_load_string()... it gets rid of the ID's so doing the foreach afterwards is pointless. I've tried it and it only returns '' on the var_dump.. This isn't coming from a file, it's coming from a string. My XML doesn't look like yours before that load_string function.. I can't output it like that because I'm using an API that outputs it in the format in my first post. I don't have control over how that outputs.